# Get click event and swipe gesture in imageswitcher in android?

Tags: android, events, click

I have an imageswitcher as the only component on the screen. I want to capture the swipe gesture and click event separately for it. But it is not able to get the events separately. If I set the onclicklistener method for imageswitcher object then it always fires onclick method even if I have swiped.

Can someone let me know the workaround to this?

Comment: i have the same problem. did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you return true from your `onFling(…)` it should consume the event and stop propagation.

Ref from this question:
[android - giving onTouch priority over onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664756/android-giving-ontouch-priority-over-onclick)