# android - giving onTouch priority over onClick

Tags: android, view, onclick, touch, swipe

I have an activity that allows users to swipe between 3 different views. Each view displays a list of images. The images have onClick events that call a new activity and makes the images full screen.
This all works ok however if I try to swipe between the 3 different views and my finger swipes over an image it will trigger the onClick event and open the image fullscreen. So I am wondering how can I put priority on onTouch (for the page/view swapping) ?

(the onTouch event uses a gestureListener and i'm using onFling and flipper methods..)
(the onClick is simply a imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() )

Answer (score 3):

If you return true from your onFling(…) it should consume the event and stop propagation.

Comment: Fantastic! That worked! It was such an obvious thing too that I wouldn't have noticed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup#java) solution for delegating a touch from parent to child view, if you need more info.

```
mDrawerLayout.post(() -> {
        Rect delegateArea = new Rect();

        mCalendarView.getHitRect(delegateArea);
        delegateArea.right += 100;
        delegateArea.bottom += 100;

        TouchDelegate touchDelegate = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea, mCalendarView);

        if (View.class.isInstance(mCalendarView.getParent())) {
            ((View) mCalendarView.getParent()).setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate);
        }
    });
```